# Native module cannot be null, expo with firebase import issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

Trying to get Firestore imported into my application but keep getting the error "Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null" I was looking through some solutions and people were saying to run `pod install` in ios but the ios folder doesn't exist in expo? Not sure what to do...

My import it `import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';` 
I am using firebase auth and that is working fine but no luck with the firestore.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `react-native-firebase with expo`. See [this](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/) guide from expo about using the firebase sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by going to node_modules > @react-native-firebase then opening the app and database folders and deleting any node_modules folders I found inside of those

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. As a solution, I didn't import from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'. I used only 'import firebase from "firebase";' and I used in code block this 'firebase.firestore()'. It is worked.